# ¿En que consiste la licencia General Public Licence versión 3 (GPLv3)?

Tags: licencias, gpl

Quiero que un software que estoy empezando sea abierto  y he visto que la GPL podría servirme. Se que las licencias GPL fuerza al programador a distribuir el código fuente y también que los trabajos sobre ese código deben tener licencias o igual o menos restrictivas, también que esto es gratuito y las obras derivadas también.

Actualmente entiendo que está la versión 3 de la licencia, pero hay temas que aún no entiendo acerca de esta licencia como su relación con las patentes de software (y todo el problema de Europa v/s USA) y cual es la diferencia con la GPLv2.

Entonces tengo esta duda. Si la GPLv3 está basada en la GPLv2 y es compatible, cual es la diferencia? Si es puede explicar la licencia completa sería excelente

Comment: ¿Formulada con fines de autorespuesta?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El texto definitivo de la licencia GPL en su tercera versión (GPLv3) fue publicado el 29 de junio de 2007 por la [Free Software Foundation](http://www.fsf.org).

Se trata de un cambio importante si tomamos en cuenta que la última revisión de la GPLv2 databa de 1991 y que el escenario jurídico y técnico relacionado al software libre ha cambiado considerablemente en todos esos años.

En la [2da Conferencia Internacional GPLv3 de fecha 21 de abril de 2006](https://fsfe.org/campaigns/gplv3/fisl-rms-transcript.es.html#licence-compatibility) Richard Stallman explicó, usando un lenguaje coloquial, los principales cambios de la GPLv3.

## Un poco de historia

El proyecto GNU, fundado en 1983 por Richard M. Stallman tiene por objetivo construir un entorno informático completamente libre. El "arma" usada para obtener esa conquista no es un programa informático, sino una pieza de texto jurídico, una licencia de software que se ha convertido en algo así como la constitución básica del movimiento denominado “copyleft“, porque el caballo de batalla en todo esto son los por todos conocidos copyright (derechos de autor). En realidad, **todo software está bajo copyright desde el momento de su publicación**. El software libre no es la excepción. El software es libre porque quien tiene el copyright decide publicarlo bajo una licencia que lo hace libre. Se trata pues de una cuestión jurídica, no de programación.

Esa es la razón de ser de la Licencia Pública General de GNU, una licencia pensada para otorgar las libertades de usar los programas con cualquier propósito, estudiar cómo funcionan, adaptarlos a las propias necesidades, copiarlos sin limite alguno, mejorarlos y distribuir las mejoras. La única condición esencial de la licencia, es que al redistribuir el programa o sus obras derivadas, siga siendo libre. Esta licencia copyleft impacta hoy no sólo en el ámbito del software, sino que ya hay numerosas experiencias de licencias para obras musicales, escritos, videos, sitios web y hasta tesis universitarias publicadas bajo términos similares.

En 1991, la Free Software Foundation publicó la GPLv2, la licencia que acompañó a gran parte del movimiento de Software Libre a lo largo de más de 16 años. Es este texto, y no el código o las virtudes de algún programador, lo que hace que el software sea libre. La cuestión es jurídica, no técnica.

Sería injusto hablar de la GPLv3 sin antes reconocer los méritos enormes de la GPLv2 y las contribuciones al Software Libre tal como lo conocemos hoy. Esta licencia, y en particular el hecho de que sea copyleft, es lo que ha permitido cultivar comunidades sólidas alrededor de los programas de computadora confeccionados, sabiendo que existe un respaldo jurídico que va a garantizar que todo aquel software que liberamos seguirá siendo libre no importa por qué manos pase ni quién lo modifique.

## ¿Por qué una nueva versión de GPL?

El motivo principal es que hoy existen una serie de amenazas que ponen en riesgo la libertad que no existían o eran muy incipientes en el momento de publicación de la GPLv2 y que por lo tanto no están contempladas en ella. Por otro lado, la comunidad de Software Libre ha crecido enormemente desde aquellos primeros años.

La misión de GPLv3 es la misma que la de sus predecesoras: Preservar la Libertad.

En esta revisión, la FSF no se ha propuesto otra misión que la de seguir cumpliendo este objetivo y ningún otro. De hecho, cambiar de una licencia a otra no es una obligación y no habrá ningún problema con aquellos programas que sigan distribuyéndose bajo versiones anteriores. El hecho de que GPLv2 y GPLv3 sean incompatibles entre si (como toda licencia copyleft) no es impedimento para que varios programas con estas diferentes licencias se distribuyan juntos. GPLv2 seguirá tan vigente como antes. Pero ahora la comunidad tendrá la versión 3 para defenderse de una serie de amenazas aparecidas en los últimos años.

## Principales cambios

En la GPLv3 **hay tres áreas de cambios importantes** según el mismo Stallman (ver enlace de más arriba). Una se refiere a la **Tivoización**, otra tiene relación con las **patentes de software** y la otra está vinculada a la **compatibilidad con otras licencias** de Software Libre.

### 1. Evitando la tivoización

Tivoización, es un término acuñado por los creadores de GPL. Tivo es un sistema de grabación digital de televisión que ejecuta software bajo GPL- por supuesto, libre.- Tivo cumple con las especificaciones de la licencia, sin embargo, se las ha ingeniado para impedir el ejercicio de algunas libertades, aún sin violar la licencia. Eso es lo que se llama tivoización.

Es decir, un truco legal en el que, cumpliendo fielmente la GPL, se implementa un sistema que impide en la práctica que las personas modifiquen el programa y lo vuelvan a ejecutar en ese hardware. Esto se logra mediante firmas digitales que hacen que sólo el software “firmado” sea ejecutado por la máquina. Cuando alguien ejerce la libertad de modificar el programa, el hardware no lo valida y torna imposible su ejecución.

GPLv3 tuvo, desde el inicio de la discusión, un foco importante en la resolución del problema de los DRM, sistemas de gestión digital de restricciones diseñados para limitar lo que las personas pueden hacer con sus entornos informáticos. Estos sistemas se están popularizando masivamente y ya casi es imposible conseguir reproductores digitales de música, teléfonos móviles o sistemas de grabación digital que no los contengan. Por otro lado, saltarlos se está convirtiendo en una acción ilegal en muchos países (la Digital Millenium Copyright Act de los EEUU es la legislación bandera en este campo).

La nueva versión de la licencia asegura que las personas puedan remover estas limitaciones sin tener riesgos legales. GPL v3 no prohibe los DRM ni el desarrollo de ninguna otra aplicación de esa naturaleza. Simplemente asegura la libertad de removerlos mediante un mecanismo jurídico que literalmente limita la “tivoización”.

La versión 3 de la GPL fue diseñada para prohibir la tivoización. No prohíbe las características malévolas del código. No prohíbe modificaciones al código para que el software informe lo que el usuario hace. No prohíbe que se modifique el software para que éste se niegue a copiar cosas o que directamente no tenga ninguna característica que le permita copiar en absoluto. Lo que si prohíbe es que se bloquee al usuario la posibilidad de hacer otras modificaciones.

Cuando la gente distribuye Productos de Usuario que incluyen software bajo la GPLv3, la sección 6 exige que le proporcionen la información necesaria para modificar ese software. «Producto de Usuario» es una expresión que viene definida de forma particular en la licencia; ejemplos de Productos de Usuario son los reproductores de música portátiles, las grabadoras de vídeo digital y los sistemas de seguridad domésticos.

**No prohíbe el DRM**

La licencia permite utilizar software publicado bajo la GPLv3 para desarrollar tecnología DRM del tipo que desee. No obstante, si lo hace, la sección 3 dice ese sistema no podrá considerarse como una medida de «protección» tecnológica efectiva, lo que significa que si una persona elimina el DRM, ella será libre de distribuir también su software, sin que la DCMA o leyes similares supongan ningún obstáculo.

Como de costumbre, la GPL de GNU no limita lo que el usuario pueda hacer con el software, sólo les impide que impongan restricciones a otros.

### 2. Patentes y licencias

El otro gran tema que aborda la GPLv3 es el de las patentes de software. Los programas de computadora están cubiertos por copyright en todo el mundo, sin embargo, en algunos países, especialmente Japón y EEUU, se ha vuelto posible registrar ideas implementadas en software bajo el sistema de patentes. Así, no sorprende encontrar en esos países patentes sobre el doble click o sobre algún algoritmo matemático específico.

Las patentes de software en ese sentido son una amenaza a la confección y distribución de programas. Podrían ser un campo minado para el desarrollo de software y la innovación.

La GPLv3 enfoca este problema considerando que la única forma de asegurar la libertad es aboliendo las patentes de software donde ya están implementadas y evitando que se implementen en aquellos países donde aún no existe ese problema.

Una licencia de software no puede solucionar este problema. Sin embargo, sí puede tratar de hacer cierto control de daños. Por eso, GPLv3 en su sección 10 tiene un resguardo de patentes explícito llamado *«cláusula de represalia por patentes»* para asegurar que usuarios y/o redistribuidores no sean llevados a juicio cuando usen, modifiquen y redistribuyan software libre. Si de todos modos alguien decide llevar a juicio por motivo de patentes, la sección 8 explica que perderían su licencia y cualquier licencia de patente que la acompañara.

A diferencia de la GPLv2, la GPLv3 contiene una licencia explícita de patentes que intenta proteger al usuario de las consecuencias de los acuerdos entre los titulares de patentes y los licenciatarios de la GPL.

**Licenciar hardware**

Cualquier bien material susceptible de quedar cubierto por copyright puede ser licenciado bajo la GPL. La GPLv3 puede utilizarse también para licenciar materiales cubiertos por otras leyes similares al copyright; por ejemplo, las máscaras de semiconductores. Así, por ejemplo, puede publicar bajo la GPL el diseño gráfico de un objeto físico o de un circuito.

En muchas situaciones el copyright no cubre la fabricación material de hardware a partir de un diseño gráfico. En tales situaciones, su licencia del diseño gráfico no ejerce ningún control sobre la manufacturación o la venta del hardware, sea cual fuere la licencia que use. En aquellos casos en que el copyright sí cubre la manufacturación de hardware, por ejemplo las máscaras IC, la GPL sí es de utilidad.

### 3. Compatibilidad entre licencias

Pensemos este escenario: tenemos dos programas ambos publicados y queremos combinarlos. ¿Cómo se distribuirá la versión combinada? Bien, un programa dice que debe ser distribuído su original más el archivo de las modificaciones, pero el otro dice que debe debe ser distribuído de la misma manera. Es imposible que ambos sean «el original» en una nueva distribución al mismo tiempo. Esto crea en muchos casos la incompatibilidad de licencias.

Con la GPLv3 se puede combinar el código publicado bajo la otra licencia con el código publicado bajo la GPL de GNU en un programa más amplio.

Todas las versiones de la GPL de GNU permiten efectuar tal combinación de forma privada; también permiten la distribución de dichas combinaciones siempre que éstas se publiquen bajo la GPL de GNU. La otra licencia es compatible con la GPL si también lo permite.

La GPLv3 es compatible con más licencias que la GPLv2; le permite efectuar combinaciones con código que tenga determinados requisitos adicionales que no figuran en la propia GPLv3. La sección 7 ofrece más información acerca de esto e incluye la lista de requisitos adicionales permitidos.

### Otros cambios importantes

Dado que la GPLv2 se escribió antes de que la distribución peer-to-peer se popularizara (bitorrent), es difícil cumplir con sus requisitos cuando se comparte código por esta vía. El mejor modo de asegurarse de cumplir con la licencia cuando distribuye código objeto bajo la GPLv2 consistiría en incluir todo el código correspondiente en el mismo torrent, lo cual es muy costoso.

La GPLv3 aborda este problema de dos maneras. En primer lugar, a quienes se bajen el torrent y envíen datos a otros como parte de ese proceso no se les exige que hagan nada especial. Esto es así porque la sección 9 dice que «La propagación de un trabajo amparado surgida simplemente como consecuencia de la transmisión entre usuarios para obtener una copia tampoco requiere aceptación. [de la licencia].» (En inglés: “Ancillary propagation of a covered work occurring solely as a consequence of using peer-to-peer transmission to receive a copy likewise does not require acceptance [of the license].”).

En segundo lugar, el punto (e) de la sección 6 de la GPLv3 está pensado para proporcionar a los distribuidores —quienes siembran inicialmente los torrent— un medio claro y directo de entregar el código fuente, indicando a los destinatarios un servidor público donde se encuentre disponible. Esto garantiza que cualquiera que quiera obtener el código fuente pueda hacerlo, y apenas supone molestias para el distribuidor.

Otros cambios incluyen una modificación en los términos de finalización para dar oportunidades de revertir posibles violaciones involuntarias, el uso y promoción de sistemas P2P y BitTorrent y la compatibilidad con otras licencias como Apache, por ejemplo.

Otra innovación fundamental de la GPLv3  ha sido en el diseño mismo de la licencia. Las versiones 1 y 2 fueron escritas por el mismo Richard Stallman, con ayuda de abogados cercanos. La construcción de GPLv3 se hizo de una manera completamente nueva, **con participación pública, consultas, reuniones, eventos y una comunidad enorme a nivel global** movilizada para asegurar que el software libre siga siendo libre.

Esta metodología no consta en el texto de la licencia, pero será sin dudas un hito en la historia de la informática... y del derecho.

## ¿Cómo actualizo de la GPLv2 a la GPLv3?

En primer lugar, incluye la nueva versión de la licencia en su paquete. Si en su proyecto está utilizando la LGPLv3, asegúrese de incluir copia tanto de la GPLv3 como de la LGPLv3, puesto que la LGPLv3 está ahora escrita como un conjunto de permisos adicionales a la GPLv3.

En segundo lugar, sustituya todas las notas de licencia v2 (normalmente en la cabecera de cada archivo) por el nuevo texto recomendado, disponible en Cómo usar licencias de GNU para su propio software. Soportará mejor el paso del tiempo, pues ya no incluye la dirección postal de la FSF.

Por supuesto, cualquier texto descriptivo (como el LÉAME) que se refiera a la licencia del paquete deberá también actualizarse adecuadamente.

## ¿Es compatible la GPLv3 con la GPLv2?

No. Muchos requisitos han cambiado entre la GPLv2 y la GPLv3, lo que significa que requisitos concretos de la GPLv2 no están presentes en la GPLv3, y viceversa. Por ejemplo, las condiciones de Anulación de la GPLv3 son considerablemente más permisivas que las de la GPLv2, y por tanto diferentes de las condiciones de Anulación de la GPLv2.

Debido a estas diferencias, las dos licencias no son compatibles: si tratara de combinar código publicado bajo la GPLv2 con código publicado bajo la GPLv3, estaría vulnerando la sección 6 de la GPLv2.

No obstante, si el código está publicado bajo la «versión 2 o posterior» de la GPL, es compatible con la GPLv3, puesto que la GPLv3 es una de las opciones que admite.

## En GPLv3 es obligatorio dar información de instalación

GPLv3 exige de forma explícita que en la redistribución se incluya toda la «Información de Instalación» necesaria, mientras que la GPLv2 no utiliza esa expresión, pero exige que en la redistribución se incluyan los scripts utilizados para controlar la compilación e instalación del ejecutable, junto con el correspondiente código fuente completo. Esto comprende parte pero no todo lo que la GPLv3 llama «Información de Instalación». Así pues, el requisito de la GPLv3 acerca de la información de instalación es más fuerte.

## Enlaces

1. [Sitio oficial](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-3.0.html)
2. [Preguntas frecuentes acerca de las licencias de GNU](https://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-faq.html#v3HowToUpgrade)
3. [Wiki oficial con algunas traducciones al castellano](http://gplv3.fsf.org/wiki/index.php/Reusable_texts)

Comment: Wow muy completo. Lo voy a leer con detenimiento :p